# Sonar service stopped after few seconds

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed Sonar on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` with all prerequisites Mysql & Java. When I start the service in console mode below error messages are appearing:

```
Running SonarQube...

wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console

wrapper  | Launching a JVM...

wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.

jvm 1    | wrapper  | Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)

wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.

wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Even, java environment variable also configured in wrapper.properties file but still the issue persists.

Someone, help me to solve this issue.

After setting the java path in wrapper.java.command (wrapper.properties) 
below error is occurring.

Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube-6.7/temp
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] 
Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonarqube-6.7/temp/conf/es
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:20 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:20 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:22 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2017.12.19 12:06:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl]
SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Please help *@Eric*

Comment: You should have a look at the log files in directory logs/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the property `wrapper.java.command` (in wrapper.conf) is incorrectly set.

The default value is `java`, if you have installed Java in a particular location, just update this value with the full path of the java executable.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the permission of jdk folder. I think its not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, i needed copy the wrapper.conf file and past on the **same path** of **wrapper exec** with this **wrapper.java.command**:

```
wrapper.java.command=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```